# WRT320N wireless router with lots of ipods connected

Tags: networking, internet, wifi, router

I want to use a [WRT320N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/EU/en/products/WRT320N) with DD-WRT as an (unprotected) access point for 80-120 iPods, iPhones, and other phones with wireless capability, as well as one wired desktop. Will this work at all (will I be able to connect this amount of devices at all)? The WRT320N will be connected to a switch and probably reach around 2MB/s, the wireless devices will only need to use one website, and if things become too slow I can block everything else, so that should not be a problem.

If I am able to connect that many devices, what are some other problems I might encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run short of channel space/responsiveness across the wireless devices. The typical rule of thumb is somewhere around 30 devices per channel, but even that was determined a while ago - before a lot of the new streaming content across the Internet (e.g. Youtube, iTunes, etc.). Even with devices capable of running on the 5 GHz band, you may still be looking at possible ceiling of roughly 60 devices with both channels (a.k.a. bands) running simultaneously.